Floquet Theory and Quantum Quench
Floquet Theory and Quantum Quench are approaches to study systems far from equilibrium (e.g. periodic driving of a closed system).
Floquet Theory helps to find a unitary operator $Q(t)$ such that it maps $H(t) - i\partial t$ to an effective static Hamiltonian $\tilde{H}$
$$\tilde{H}|n\rangle=\left(Q H Q^{\dagger}-i Q \partial_t Q^{\dagger}\right)|n\rangle=\epsilon_n|n\rangle$$
We then study the corresponding steady-state dynamics. (e.g. correlation functions of different physical observables)
On the other hand, quantum quench is a setup that first drives the system (e.g. modulates the coupling constant periodically) and stops at a certain time $\tau$, and studies the in-quench and post-quench dynamics.
My question is conceptual. Are these two approaches equivalent? My impression is that quantum quench is a much more general methodology and includes the Floquet theory approach... If we set the quench time $\tau \to \infty$, will the dynamics equivalent to the one produced by Floquet theory?
